# When I clicking mouse on special element, ajax worked but why with element.click() will reloading page?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I wrote below code for woocommerce that when quantity is less than one, click link of remove in cart, but after clicking, the page refreshed, while with mouse, fire ajax without refreshing page.

```js
document.querySelector('.product-details a[data-product_id="' + product_id + '"] ').click()
```

The below code is for min cart on top page that show quantity and has remove links.I want to use the this remove link.

```html
<div class="pull-right top-cart hidden-xs">
    <div class="tbay-topcart">
        <div id="cart" class="dropdown version-1 open">
        <span class="text-skin cart-icon">
            <i class="icofont-shopping-cart"></i>
                 <span class="mini-cart-items" style="opacity: 1;"> 4  </span>
        </span>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle mini-cart" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" role="button"
               aria-haspopup="true" data-delay="0" href="#" title="Show cart">

                <span class="sub-title">My cart<i class="icofont-rounded-down"></i> </span>
                <span class="mini-cart-subtotal" style="opacity: 1;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">20,000&nbsp;<span
                                class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span><i
                            class="icofont-rounded-down"></i></span>

            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content" style="opacity: 1;">

                    <div class="mini_cart_content">
                        <div class="mini_cart_inner">
                            <div class="mcart-border">
                                <ul class="cart_list product_list_widget ">
                                    <li id="mcitem-30da227c6b5b9e2482b6b221c711edfd">
                                        <a href="/product/%d8%ac%d8%b3%d8%a8-%da%a9%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%a8/">
                                            <img width="160" height="130"
                                                 src="wp-content/uploads/2019/12/7-cm-90-yard-45-micron-1-160x130.png"
                                                 class="attachment-woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail size-woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail wp-post-image"
                                                 alt="book"> </a>
                                        <div class="product-details">
                                            <a href="/cart/?remove_item=30da227c6b5b9e2482b6b221c711edfd&amp;_wpnonce=bebb559ebd"
                                               class="remove remove_from_cart_button" aria-label="remove-this-item"
                                               data-product_id="4465" data-product_sku=""
                                               data-cart_item_key="30da227c6b5b9e2482b6b221c711edfd">x</a>
                                            <a href="/product/%d8%ac%d8%b3%d8%a8-%da%a9%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%a8/">book</a>

                                            <span class="quantity">1</span>
                                            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">8,000&nbsp;<span
                                                        class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span></div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul><!-- end product list -->
                                <p class="total">total: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">20,000&nbsp;<span
                                                class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span></p>
                                <p class="buttons">
                                    <a href="/cart/" class="button wc-forward view-cart">cart</a>
                                    <a href="/checkout/" class="button checkout wc-forward">checkout</a>
                                </p>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code worted in quantity php that shows in under my products, when I clicked on minus or plus, change data attribute of element add_to_cart

```php
    <div class="box-quantity">
        <span class="title-qty"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Quantity', 'greenmart' ) ?></span>
        <div class="quantity">

            <input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
            <input 
            type="number" 
            class="input-text qty text" 
            data-step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" 
            data-min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" 
            data-max="<?php echo esc_attr( 0 < $max_value ? $max_value : '' ); ?>" 
            name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" 
            title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'greenmart' ) ?>" 
            size="4" pattern="<?php echo esc_attr( $pattern ); ?>" 
            data-inputmode="<?php echo esc_attr( $inputmode ); ?>"
            aria-labelledby="<?php echo esc_attr( $labelledby ); ?>" />
            <input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
        </div>
    </div>
```

the below code is my script, first, I checked that data attribute (add to cart) changed then update my cart.
but I can not remove one product from my cart without refresh page.

```js
<script>
const x_elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.ajax_add_to_cart')];
                let observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
                    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {

                        let product_id = mutation.target.getAttribute('data-product_id');
                        const product_qty = mutation.target.getAttribute(mutation.attributeName);
                        let current_val = mutation.target.getAttribute(mutation.attributeName);


                        console.log(mutation.target.getAttribute(mutation.attributeName) + '-' + mutation.target.getAttribute('data-product_id') + '-' + mutation.oldValue);

                        let minus_action =
                            document.querySelector('[data-product-id="' + product_id + '"]  input.minus');
                        let plus_action =
                            document.querySelector('[data-product-id="' + product_id + '"]  input.plus');

                        if (current_val == '0') {
                            minus_action.style.opacity = 0;
                            minus_action.disabled = true;

                        } else if (current_val == '1') {
                            minus_action.value = '×';
                            minus_action.style.opacity = 1;
                            minus_action.disabled = false;

                        } else {
                            minus_action.value = '-';
                            minus_action.style.opacity = 1;
                            minus_action.disabled = false;
                        }


                            minus_action.addEventListener('click', () => {

                                if (current_val == '0' || current_val == 0 || current_val < 1 || mutation.oldValue == 0 &&current_val == 1 ) {

                                document.querySelector('.product-details a[data-product_id="' + product_id + '"] ').click();

                                console.log('clicked= '+document.querySelector('.product-details a[data-product_id="' + product_id + '"] '))
                                 }
                            });



                        const data = {
                            action: 'woocommerce_add_2_cart',
                            product_id: product_id,
                            product_qty: product_qty,
                            product_qty_old: mutation.oldValue
                        };


                        jQuery.ajax({

                            type: 'post',
                            url: woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
                            data: data,
                            beforeSend: function (response) {
                                minus_action.parentNode.style.opacity='.5';
                                minus_action.disabled='true';
                                plus_action.disabled='true';
                            },
                            complete: function (response) {
                                minus_action.parentNode.style.opacity='1';
                                minus_action.disabled='false';
                                plus_action.disabled='false';
                            },
                            success: function (response) {

                                if (response.error & response.product_url) {
                                    window.location = response.product_url;
                                    return;
                                } else {
                                    var fragments = response.fragments;

                                    if (fragments) {
                                        jQuery.each(fragments, function (key, value) {
                                            jQuery(key).replaceWith(value);
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        });

                    });
                });


                x_elements.forEach(ele => {
                    ele.setAttribute('data-quantity', '0');
                    observer.observe(ele, {
                            attributes: true,
                            attributeOldValue: true,
                            attributeFilter: ['data-quantity']

                        }
                    );
                });


            </script>
```

Comment: As above, show more code please.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined "href" in anchors. So mimicking click do redirect as expected. You can set href="#" in anchors. But on the other hand, I do not understand why clicking with mouse does not redirect the page. I'm a bit confused.